# Express application returns empty body

Tags: html, node.js, express

My express application returns {} when it gets a request.

```
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded ({ extended: false }));

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.body);
        console.log(req.body);
});
```

This is the html that I am using to send the form

```
<div class="login-form">

  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="text" class="login-field" placeholder="username" id="username" name="username" required>
    <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="password" class="login-field" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password" required>
    <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" type="submit">register</button>
  <a class="login-link" href="login.html">Already have an account?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where's your XHR request that's sending this form data? Does `console.log(req.body)` show anything?

Comment: Can you change the outside `div` to be a `form`?  I believe this is required for the fields to be included in the `POST` body.

Comment: I added the form inside the login form div and restarted nginx but I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `input` tags in `form` tag as follows:

```html
<div class="login-form">
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" class="login-field" placeholder="username" id="username" name="username" required>
            <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="password" class="login-field" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" type="submit">register</button>
        <a class="login-link" href="login.html">Already have an account?</a>
    </form>
</div>
```